# Images working locally, but not working once deployed on Google App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have an app.yaml file which looks like this:

```
application: segmentize
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /css
  static_dir: css

- url: /img(.*\.(gif|png|jpg))
  static_files: img/\1
  upload: img(.*\.(gif|png|jpg))

- url: /
  script: index.app

skip_files:
- ^(.*/)?app\.yaml
- ^(.*/)?app\.yml
- ^(.*/)?index\.yaml
- ^(.*/)?index\.yml
- ^(.*/)?#.*#
- ^(.*/)?.*~
- ^(.*/)?.*\.py[co]
- ^(.*/)?.*/RCS/.*
- ^(.*/)?\..*
- ^(.*/)?dev
- ^(.*/)?old_ver
- ^(.*/)?resources
```

The images all display fine locally. However, once deployed, they show as broken.

Images in the html are set as follows:

```
<img src="/img/welcomeimg.png">
```

Are the images just not uploading when I deploy? What's causing this? The css folder seems to deploy with no issue.

Comment: the app engine is case sensitive file system, check for that.

Comment: and I'm guessing you are not using the `skip_files`, but if you are.. can you please include that as well?

Comment: @ShayErlichmen I checked all of the file names. Everything is lowercase.

Comment: @Lipis I've updated my question to show the skip_files section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the slash in the end of the `img` in the `url` and in the `upload` section:

```
- url: /img/(.*\.(gif|png|jpg))
  static_files: img/\1
  upload: img/(.*\.(gif|png|jpg))
```